# condenameOne 404 Not found

Tags: codenameone

IDE: NetBeans/
OS
Simulator

My Wampserver is running in port 8080,

I create a text file under www directory, the URL that I am using is :

> http://localhost:8080/codenameone/tst.txt

and when I run the code  it returns

> Error 404: Not found.

I just did that and checked the URL multiple times already, even when I copy the URL in the URL bar it works but when i run the code with codenameOne no.

Comment: It the CN1 simulator is not running on the same machine as your Wamp server, then you can't use a localhost URL.  If it is running on the same machine, then check your Java Proxy settings.... it may be preventing you from accessing localhost because it is effectively on a different local network.  Otherwise, post some code here so that people can see it and comment.